# Creating a geoTIFF from PostGIS raster column

Tags: python, postgis, raster, gdal, geoalchemy

I am able to retrieve raw raster data from a PostGIS raster in a PostgreSQL database using SQL Alchmey. I can get the raw data directly from the database. Now I would like to create a geoTIFF file from the raw data. Here is the raw raster data from the database.

0100000100000000000000D03F000000000000D0BF0000000000804140000000000000F43F00000000000000000000000000000000E6100000010001004A003C1CC600000000

[image]

The above image is a screenshot of the database table that I am accessing through SQL Alchemy. Is there a way that I can create a geotiff from this raw data using gdal in python? I have looked for a similar workflow, but couldn't find any examples on creating a tiff directly from raw raster data.

Comment: @Kuba Szostak what is this data[0][0]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Alex for pointing me in the right direction. But I did not have to clip the raster. I am trying to upload the data from postgis database to geotiff using the requests module. For that purpose the following code did the trick.

```py
     import psycopg2
     sql = """SELECT ST_AsGDALRaster(rast, 'GTiff', ARRAY['COMPRESS=LZW']) as tiff FROM {0}.{1} WHERE id = {2}""".format(schema,table,date)
     cur.execute(sql)
     data = cur.fetchall()
     tif_data = data[0][0] #This can passed as the data variable in the requests.put function
     with open("d:/gis/pg_raster.tif", "wb") as f:
          f.write(tif_data)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can query for TIFF data directly:

The query:

```
SELECT
    ST_AsTIFF(ST_Union(rast), 'LZW') as tiff,
FROM {dataset_name}
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('{region_string}'), '4326'), rast)
```

Then you can use GDAL or RasterIO to write it to a file.

(You may even be able to just dump the binary direct to a file.)

Comment: Ah, sorry. That's a WKT representation of an area. This example gets all the raster chunks that intersect a polygon. (Hence the need for ST_Union)

Answer (score 2):

I am going to provide a separate answer because although it may seem obvious to some familiar with `PostGIS`, `GDAL`, and `rasterio` libraries, I had a heck of a time actually getting the raster loaded in to my python environment.

From start to finish, here's what works for me:

```
import sqlalchemy
import rasterio
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile
url = sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(drivername='postgresql+psycopg2',
                                database='my_db',
                                username='postgres',
                                password='my_password',
                                host='localhost',
                                port=5432)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url)
sql = ("SELECT ST_AsGDALRaster(rast, 'GTiff') AS tiff "
       "{0}.{1} WHERE rid = 1".format('public', 'raster_name')
with engine.connect() as cnxn:
    result = cnxn.execute(sql)
with MemoryFile(result.fetchall()[0][0].tobytes()) as memfile:
    ds = memfile.open()
ds.meta
```

Output:

```
{'driver': 'GTiff',
 'dtype': 'uint16',
 'nodata': 0.0,
 'width': 40,
 'height': 40,
 'count': 9,
 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32613),
 'transform': Affine(20.0, 0.0, 697920.0, 0.0, -20.0, 3984120.0)}
```

And to save file to current directory:

```
with rasterio.open('output.tif', 'w', **ds.profile) as dst:
    dst.write(ds.read())
```